# Tool that generates a mindmap for a given text

Tags: python, nlp, mind-mapping, deep-learning

Hey I am looking at a tool or software(open source preferred) that does provide me a mindmap of any text provided

I don't have any preferences for the language. 
For example, I would like to pass a small paragraph that tells a story and I would like to see that entire paragraph visually with the words or sentences linked/mapped to each other related sentences with some kind of relation name mapped between them.

Comment: Please give an example. For instance, how would it map the text of your question?

Comment: What languages should it support?

Comment: This doesn't make a mindmap but gives related words, is this the kind of solution you are looking for? https://relatedwords.org/ This one does make a mindmap but the results are not as good as the first: https://visuwords.com/

Comment: @Thomas visuWords.com is kind of what I am looking for but I want a sentence to be passed and the mindmap for that to be generated

Comment: @NicolasRaoul updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for editing. In addition, please add a real-life example, with a real sentence and an image of the output. Especially please mention the relation names. Thanks!